# How to write a callback in VB6?

Tags: vb6, callback

How do you write a callback function in VB6? I know AddressOf gets you the function gets the address in a Long. But how do I call the function with the memory address? Thanks!

Comment: What do you need the callback for? The answer will differ drastically depending on that.

Comment: I have a function in a module that takes more than a few cycles. I was thinking about using a callback from the function to let the caller know it's progress. So I'd be using it almost like an event, except from a function not a class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do.

To [invert control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control), just create the callback function in a class. Then use an instance of the class (an object) to make the callback.

- If you need to switch between different routines at run time, have separate classes that implement the same interface - a [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).
- IMHO `AddressOf` is far too complicated and risky to use in this way.

`AddressOf` should **only** be used if you need to [register callback functions](http://vb.mvps.org/hardcore/html/theultimatehackprocedurepointers.htm) with the Windows API.

Comment: I posted my intention on the main comment thread. But I'll repost here: I have a function in a module that takes more than a few cycles. I was thinking about using a callback from the function to let the caller know it's progress. So I'd be using it almost like an event, except from a function not a class.

Comment: Oops, I overlooked those comments. Well, couldn't you pass in an object to the function, and call back into the object? Or put the function into a new class, and raise events from the class? Both are nice clean OO patterns. Workarounds for the lack of delegates in VB6.

Answer (score 8):

[This post](http://www.vbforums.com/showpost.php?p=2046053&postcount=5) on vbforums.com gives an example of how to use AddressOf and the CallWindowProc function to execute a callback procedure.

Code from the post:

```
Private Declare Function CallWindowProc _
 Lib "user32.dll" Alias "CallWindowProcA" ( _
 ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, _
 ByVal hwnd As Long, _
 ByVal msg As Long, _
 ByVal wParam As Long, _
 ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

Private Sub ShowMessage( _
 msg As String, _
 ByVal nUnused1 As Long, _
 ByVal nUnused2 As Long, _
 ByVal nUnused3 As Long)
    'This is the Sub we will call by address
    'it only use one argument but we need to pull the others
    'from the stack, so they are just declared as Long values
    MsgBox msg
End Sub

Private Function ProcPtr(ByVal nAddress As Long) As Long
    'Just return the address we just got
    ProcPtr = nAddress
End Function

Public Sub YouCantDoThisInVB()
    Dim sMessage As String
    Dim nSubAddress As Long

    'This message will be passed to our Sub as an argument
    sMessage = InputBox("Please input a short message")
    'Get the address to the sub we are going to call
    nSubAddress = ProcPtr(AddressOf ShowMessage)
    'Do the magic!
    CallWindowProc nSubAddress, VarPtr(sMessage), 0&, 0&, 0&
End Sub
```

Comment: Quite risky to use AddressOf like this. Why not just create the callback function in a class and use an instance (an object) to make the callback?

Comment: ... If you make a mistake, your whole app will die with an unhandled exception error.

Comment: @MarkJ: I agree.  This is just an example of one way to do this--not necessarily one I would choose.